# Is it possible to pass env vars to a template in azure devops pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am struggling to find out if there is a way to satisfy my usecase here, so I have a pipeline which makes use of templates and one template is a bit generic and reused a bit, so lets imagine something like this:

```
parameters:
  - name: displayName
    type: string
  - name: type
    type: string

steps:
  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: ${{parameters.displayName}}
    env:
      # This needs to be passed in somehow
    inputs:
      filePath: "somePowershellFile.ps1"
      arguments: ${{parameters.type}}
```

Now the problem I have is that this template could be used for different purposes based on an argument passed in, so ideally I need to be able to pass it an object for it to be able to populate the env vars correctly for the given script to function.

Here is an example of how it would be called within a pipeline:

```
steps:
  # other build steps
  - template: my-template.yml
    parameters:
      displayName: Do Something Cool
      type: CoolThing1
  - template: my-template.yml
    parameters:
      displayName: Do Something Else
      type: CoolThing2
```

So is there a way to pass in the env vars with the template? I had envisioned something like:

```
  - template: my-template.yml
    env:
      SomeEnvVar1: $(SomeValue) # These should be passed into the template env section
      SomeEnvVar2: $(SomeOtherValue)
    parameters:
      displayName: Do Something Cool
      type: CoolThing2
```

However that doesnt seem correct and I cant find any documented way of being able to pass in complex objects in a way to assign to the `env` section in the templates content.

So is there a way to do this? as this way I can have one yml reused a whole lot vs having to write several bespoke ymls which are all 99% the same other than the env vars being pulled in.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you could accomplish it by passing in an object and using `each` to iterate over the values.

Something like this:

```
parameters:
  - name: displayName
    type: string
  - name: type
    type: string
  - name: environmentVariables
    type: object

steps:
  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: ${{parameters.displayName}}
    env:
      ${{ each environmentVariable in parameters.environmentVariables }}: 
        ${{ insert }}: 
          ${{ environmentVariable.key }}: ${{ environmentVariable.value }}
```

Then when calling the template,

```
- template: foo.yml
  parameters:
    displayName: foo
    type: bar
    environmentVariables:
      x: qux
      y: quy
      z: quz
```

Note: I haven't tested this so it might not be syntactically perfect, but that should be pretty close.